# TextBlock size not updating properly when binding

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have flowing `TextBlock`:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,10,15,10" Name="txtMessage"/>

</Grid>
```

When I'm assigning text using following code:

```
this.txtMessage.Text = message;
```

The control that contains above grid is resizing properly and automatically change size to fit whole message text and everything is working as expected.

When I change `TextBlock` to following:

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,10,15,10" Text="{Binding Message}"/>
```

Where `Message` is dependency property. The text is assigned but is cut and ends on original size of containing control.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting HorizontalAlignment to "Stretch" for your text box...

Comment: This is not changing anything, the problem is parent control. With assiging text in code, parent is resized, with binding parent is not resized.

Comment: I've put that Grid in a UserControl which resizes properly in both cases. Maybe you have to show more of your code.

Comment: My parent is RadWindow (telerik) and it behaves like I described. Window is only resized when message assigned from code. Not during binding.

Comment: I have the same behavior than Clemens, unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I will try to create some more code sample

Comment: May be this (http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/window/radwindow-doesn-39-t-resize-to-its-contents.aspx) might help for RadWindow. They are measuring differently.

Comment: Ok, I tried reproduce this issue with normal window, but I cannot, so it looks like this is RadWindow issue. I will report this on telerik forums.